# Why ASP.NET MVC 2 will have its own client-side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am interested what are possible reasons that ASP.NET MVC 2 will have its own client-side validation instead of merging with [xVal validation framework](http://xval.codeplex.com/)? Has someone from ASP.NET MVC team blogged about it?

Comment: just wanted to chime in to say, xVal rocks!

Answer (score 0):

They are providing a way to plug in some other library for client-side validation.

[Haacked blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/10/01/asp.net-mvc-preview-2-released.aspx):

> Client-Side Validation – ASP.NET MVC 2 includes the jQuery validation library to provide client-side validation based on the model’s validation metadata. It is possible to hook in alternative client-side validation libraries by writing an adapter which adapts the client library to the JSON metadata in a manner similar to the xVal validation framework.